# How do I generate a random point on a circles circumference in 3D space?

Tags: geometry

I have a position vector and a normal vector that describes a plane. The plane is always orthogonal to the position vector. On this plane is a circle with its center at the position vector. How do I generate a random point on that circle with a given radius *r*? I know that in 2d space, I can do

`x = cos(2 * PI * random) * radius`
`y = sin(2 * PI * random) * radius`

but... I don't know how to translate that to a circle on a plane.

I tried to find a way to use the position vector and normal vector to generate points, but I just can't think of a correct way to do so. I might not be familiar enough with planes.

Comment: You should be able to define a translation matrix to move from the co-ordinate origin to the position vector, and a matrix to rotate to the normal vector. Multiply them and that should get you a mapping from a circle on the (x, y) plane at (0, 0, 0) to the position you want.

Comment: "the plane is always orthogonal to the position vector": why do you need the normal vector if your position vector can serve as normal vector? Just for the case it is 0?

Comment: Botion Man, `x = cos(2 * PI * random) * radius y = sin(2 * PI * random) * radius` will cluster points in the circle's middle.  Is that intended?  Perhaps you want a distribution more even about the area of a circle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first we need two base vectors in the circle plane.

The first one is arbitrary vector orthogonal to normal `n`:

Choose component of normal with the largest magnitude, then component with the second magnitude.

Exchange their values, negate the largest, and make the third component zero (note that dot product of result with normal is zero, so they are othogonal)

For example, if `n.y` is the largest and `n.z` is the second, make

```
v = (0, n.z, -n.y)
```

Then calculate the second base vector using vector product

```
u = n x v
```

Normalize vectors `v` and `u` (make unit magnitude).

Now we can generate a random point on circumference using center point `c` (your `position`, I think):

```
rho = 2 * PI * random

f.x = c.x + radius * v.x * cos(rho) + radius * u.x * sin(rho)
f.y = c.y + radius * v.y * cos(rho) + radius * u.y * sin(rho)
f.z = c.z + radius * v.z * cos(rho) + radius * u.z * sin(rho)
```

Comment: In the meantime, I managed to solve my problem poorly. Maybe I should have added this information in the OP, but the position vector is actually a look direction p. I selected a point of the circle on the xz plane, then rotated that point around an *axis* orthogonal to the look direction *axis (x = -p.z, y = 0, z = p.x)* by *p*'s angle to (0, 1, 0) (straight up). Then I added the look direction *p* to the point to move the circle point around (ridiculous lol). Your solution looks cleaner, I will try to use it. ty!